# Google Map does not display - no changes made to code

Tags: google-maps

Please someone tell me I am not going mad.  I've spent all weekend on a 222 line project which worked.  Next time I go back to it, without any changes, it now not works either testing locally or online.  In short, the Google Map does not display.

Thinking I was going mad I stripped to code right back to the basics, to the point that I have the following:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Test Map</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { 
          height:                   100%;
        }

        body {
          height:                   100%; 
          margin:                   0; 
          padding:                  0;
          background-image:         url('background9.jpg');
          background-color:         #B3CDE6;
          background-repeat:        no-repeat;
          background-attachment:    fixed;
          background-position:      right bottom; 
          background-size:          cover;
        }

        h {
            color:                  #000000;
            font-family:            Verdana, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
            font-size:              12px; 
            display:                inline;
            text-align:             center;

        }

        #map-canvas { 
            height:                     100%;
            width:                      75%;
            margin-left:                auto;
            margin-right:               auto;
            border-right-width:         2px;
            border-right-color:         #ffffff;
            border-right-style:         solid;
            border-left-width:          2px;
            border-left-color:          #ffffff;
            border-left-style:          solid;
        }
    </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
    var map;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    function initialize() 
    {
        var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.144178,-2.254122)
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
    };
    
</script>  

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I tired and missing something obvious here or has it been known for the Google API to go offline?  The above generates no errors during testing, neither does the original project.

Here is the code from my main project which still refuses to work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Track The T's</title>

<style type="text/css">
        html { 
          height:                   100%;
        }

        body {
          height:                   100%; 
          margin:                   0; 
          padding:                  0;
          background-image:         url('background9.jpg');
          background-color:         #B3CDE6;
          background-repeat:        no-repeat;
          background-attachment:    fixed;
          background-position:      right bottom; 
          background-size:          cover;
        }

        h {
            color:                  #000000;
            font-family:            Verdana, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
            font-size:              12px; 
            display:                inline;
            text-align:             center;

        }

        #map-canvas { 
            height:                     100%;
            width:                      75%;
            margin-left:                auto;
            margin-right:               auto;
            border-right-width:         2px;
            border-right-color:         #ffffff;
            border-right-style:         solid;
            border-left-width:          2px;
            border-left-color:          #ffffff;
            border-left-style:          solid;
        }

        .pop_up_box_text {
          font-family:              Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
          font-size:                16px; 
          line-height:              22px; 
          color:                    #ffffff; 
          display:                  inline; 
        }
    
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="infobox/infobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Set up map    

    var map;
    var pop_up_info = "border: 0px solid black; background-color: #ffffff; padding:15px; margin-top: 8px; border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 1px 1px #888;";

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    function initialize() {
        var store_pins  = new Array();
        var pin_marker  = new Array();
        var pin_info    = new Array();
        var pin_infoop  = new Array();
        var pin_infotxt = new Array();
        
        // Style Map

         var mapStyle = [
          {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "on" },
              { "color": "#0280ff" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "landscape.natural",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "on" },
              { "color": "#fffae9" }
            ]
          },{
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "elementType": "labels.text"  }
        ];
        
        store_pins = [
            ['Bellingham Co-Op', 55.144178, -2.254122,'pin','bellinghamcoop.jpg','Staff at Bellingham Co-Op'],
            ['Leicester Tigers - Kingston Park', 55.018754, -1.672230,'rugby','kingparktigers.jpg','Stu with the Leicester Tigers Rugby Team'],
            ['North Shields RFC', 55.020768, -1.456395,'rugby','northshieldsrfc.jpg','<a href="http://www.pitchero.com/clubs/northshields/" target="_new">North Shields RFC</a>'],
            ['Mad March Mare - Hexham Race Course', 54.955180, -2.129021,'pin','mrussellhexham.jpg','Mark Russell at the <a href="http://www.madmarchmare.co.uk" target="_new">Mad March Mare</a>'],
            ['Richard Shotton - Dubai', 25.022600, 55.368939,'pin','rshottondubai.jpg','Richard Shotton in Dubai'],
            ['Rob Parker and Micky Hall - Vietnam', 21.029487, 105.848402,'pin','rparkervietnam.jpg','Rob Parker and Micky Hall - Vietnam'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Dohar', 25.266629, 51.558743,'pin','rdixondohar.jpg','Roy Dixon - Dohar'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Madrid', 40.491656,  -3.591842,'pin','rdixonmadrid.jpg','Roy Dixon - Madrid'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Portugal', 38.769848, -9.128727,'pin','rdixonportugal.jpg','Roy Dixon - Portugal'],
            ['Steven Blair - Dorking', 51.235004, -0.333590,'pin','sblairdorking.jpg','Steven Blair - Dorking'],
            ['Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge', 54.966981, -2.014240,'rugby','tynedale1stcorbridge.jpg','<a href="http://www.tynedalerfc.co.uk/" target="_new">Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge</a>'],
            ['Tynedale RFC - Corbridge', 54.965673, -2.009380,'rugby','tynedalerfccorbridge.jpg','<a href="http://www.tynedalerfc.co.uk/" target="_new">Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge</a>'],
            ['The Hawick PSA Team', 55.421825, -2.797123,'rugby','hawickpsa.jpg','The Hawick PSA Team'] // NO COMMA ON LAST ENTRY
        ]

        var myOptions = {
            center:                 new google.maps.LatLng(55.144178, -2.254122),
            zoom:                   8,
            minZoom:                3,
            styles:                 mapStyle
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

        // Main Loop
        

}
</script>

</head>
<body>  
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get nothing in the way of a map, not even a grey box where the map should be which I have seen when I have made small errors in the past, like forgetting to put in zoom: 8, under the options.

Comment: Notice how your code snippet now works? It invalidates your question if you edit the reason why it doesn't work out of your code (in the first case, it was because you forgot to set the zoom, in the second case it was because you used an HTML comment in your CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** A CSS comment is denoted by /* comment */, you cannot use HTML comments  in your CSS.

Also, my first answer contained the **exact code** you initially posted (I used StackOverflow's "Copy Snippet to Answer" button. You edited your originally question (that I answered correctly), which is why my originally answer above, is no longer applicable.

**EDIT:** It appears that you've edited your code snippet again while I was in the middle of answering it and fixed it yourself.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Track The T's</title>

<!--Set up the CSS styles-->
<style type="text/css">
        html { 
          height:                   100%;
        }

        body {
          height:                   100%; 
          margin:                   0; 
          padding:                  0;
          background-image:         url('background9.jpg');
          background-color:         #B3CDE6;
          background-repeat:        no-repeat;
          background-attachment:    fixed;
          background-position:      right bottom; 
          background-size:          cover;
        }

        h {
            color:                  #000000;
            font-family:            Verdana, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
            font-size:              12px; 
            display:                inline;
            text-align:             center;

        }

          /* Stylise the map canvas */
        #map-canvas { 
            height:                     100%;
            width:                      75%;
            margin-left:                auto;
            margin-right:               auto;
            border-right-width:         2px;
            border-right-color:         #ffffff;
            border-right-style:         solid;
            border-left-width:          2px;
            border-left-color:          #ffffff;
            border-left-style:          solid;
        }

        /* Stylise the InfoBox text */
        .pop_up_box_text {
          font-family:              Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
          font-size:                16px; 
          line-height:              22px; 
          color:                    #ffffff; 
          display:                  inline; 
        }
    
</style>

<!--Connect to the google maps api using your api key-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

<!--Connect to the infobox javascript library. This is used later to create the pop-up windows -->
<script src="infobox/infobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Set up map    

    var map;
    var pop_up_info = "border: 0px solid black; background-color: #ffffff; padding:15px; margin-top: 8px; border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 1px 1px #888;";

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    function initialize() {
        var store_pins  = new Array();
        var pin_marker  = new Array();
        var pin_info    = new Array();
        var pin_infoop  = new Array();
        var pin_infotxt = new Array();
        
        // Style Map

         var mapStyle = [
          {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "on" },
              { "color": "#0280ff" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "landscape.natural",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "on" },
              { "color": "#fffae9" }
            ]
          },{
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "elementType": "labels.text"  }
        ];
        
        store_pins = [
            ['Bellingham Co-Op', 55.144178, -2.254122,'pin','bellinghamcoop.jpg','Staff at Bellingham Co-Op'],
            ['Leicester Tigers - Kingston Park', 55.018754, -1.672230,'rugby','kingparktigers.jpg','Stu with the Leicester Tigers Rugby Team'],
            ['North Shields RFC', 55.020768, -1.456395,'rugby','northshieldsrfc.jpg','<a href="http://www.pitchero.com/clubs/northshields/" target="_new">North Shields RFC</a>'],
            ['Mad March Mare - Hexham Race Course', 54.955180, -2.129021,'pin','mrussellhexham.jpg','Mark Russell at the <a href="http://www.madmarchmare.co.uk" target="_new">Mad March Mare</a>'],
            ['Richard Shotton - Dubai', 25.022600, 55.368939,'pin','rshottondubai.jpg','Richard Shotton in Dubai'],
            ['Rob Parker and Micky Hall - Vietnam', 21.029487, 105.848402,'pin','rparkervietnam.jpg','Rob Parker and Micky Hall - Vietnam'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Dohar', 25.266629, 51.558743,'pin','rdixondohar.jpg','Roy Dixon - Dohar'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Madrid', 40.491656,  -3.591842,'pin','rdixonmadrid.jpg','Roy Dixon - Madrid'],
            ['Roy Dixon - Portugal', 38.769848, -9.128727,'pin','rdixonportugal.jpg','Roy Dixon - Portugal'],
            ['Steven Blair - Dorking', 51.235004, -0.333590,'pin','sblairdorking.jpg','Steven Blair - Dorking'],
            ['Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge', 54.966981, -2.014240,'rugby','tynedale1stcorbridge.jpg','<a href="http://www.tynedalerfc.co.uk/" target="_new">Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge</a>'],
            ['Tynedale RFC - Corbridge', 54.965673, -2.009380,'rugby','tynedalerfccorbridge.jpg','<a href="http://www.tynedalerfc.co.uk/" target="_new">Tynedale 1st XV - Corbridge</a>'],
            ['The Hawick PSA Team', 55.421825, -2.797123,'rugby','hawickpsa.jpg','The Hawick PSA Team'] // NO COMMA ON LAST ENTRY
        ]

        var myOptions = {
            center:                 new google.maps.LatLng(55.144178, -2.254122),
            zoom:                   8,
            minZoom:                3,
            styles:                 mapStyle
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

        // Main Loop
        

}
</script>

</head>
<body>  
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid.  Time to start counting those sheep.

Many thanks Adam, you've saved me from a sleepless night!

I hadn't changed any code, but I did go through and comment it!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way your snippet ever "worked" without providing both a position and **a zoom** when you initialize your map.

Kudos for providing a nice, short, test case.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Test Map</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { 
          height:                   100%;
        }

        body {
          height:                   100%; 
          margin:                   0; 
          padding:                  0;
          background-image:         url('background9.jpg');
          background-color:         #B3CDE6;
          background-repeat:        no-repeat;
          background-attachment:    fixed;
          background-position:      right bottom; 
          background-size:          cover;
        }

        h {
            color:                  #000000;
            font-family:            Verdana, 'Geneva', sans-serif;
            font-size:              12px; 
            display:                inline;
            text-align:             center;

        }

        #map-canvas { 
            height:                     100%;
            width:                      75%;
            margin-left:                auto;
            margin-right:               auto;
            border-right-width:         2px;
            border-right-color:         #ffffff;
            border-right-style:         solid;
            border-left-width:          2px;
            border-left-color:          #ffffff;
            border-left-style:          solid;
        }
    </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    var map;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    function initialize() 
    {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.144178,-2.254122),
          zoom:12
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
    };
    
</script>  

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good spot Adam.  I must have missed this when copying the test code across.  Sadly though this is present in my main code :-( so I am still no further forward.  I have now added an additional code snippet of the main project, although I have removed a large section which creates the markers from an array as this is working.